# Why isn't NaN finite?

Tags: javascript, nan

Testing the `isFinite` function I see that `NaN` is an **infinite** number (even if it's *not a number* `:-)`).

```
isFinite(NaN) // returns false
```

What's the logic behind this? Why isn't `NaN` finite?

Comment: It's not a number. That seems more like infinity than a number, which isn't.

Comment: @MarkLinus the `NaN` constant represents nonsense bit arrangements in floating point values. Because it's "not a number", it cannot have any properties that numbers can have. It's not finite, and it's also not infinite. It's not even, and it's not odd. It's not positive, and it's not negative. It's not a number :)

Comment: If there was an `isInfinite()` method, it too would return `false`.

Comment: Fun fact: `isFinite(null)` returns `true`.

Comment: @EfrainReyes Yes, because `Number(null) === 0`. :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As Dave Newton said, NaN is not a number, and then you have to consider that it isn't finite nor infinite.
The same occurs to these:

```
NaN > 0  // false
NaN < 0  // false
```

You might want to read these articles:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isFinite

Comment: Even it's *not a number* its constructor is `Number`. ;-)

Comment: I know. It's an instance of `Number` class. However, its value is not considered a number itself.

Answer (score 3):

Because it is not a numeric value...and finite/infinite is applicable only to numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Because an infinite number... is still a number. NaN isn't a number in any possible sense.

It's like an error in Matrix.

Answer (score 1):

The result of any arithmetic operation on NaN is NaN.

The result of any logic operation on NaN is false.

Answer (score -3):

Finite means capable of being counted.  It has to return true or false for isFinite.  I think it makes more sense for NaN to be infinite.

Comment: Actually, there is both a "countable infinity", e.g. the set of integers, and an "uncountable infinity", e.g. the set of real numbers. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinity